# Read from serial in Python

Tags: python, serial-port

I have a [weight scale](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07JH21KXF)

Which is connected to the serial port, and I'm trying to know the weight is currently reading.
This is the code I'm using in Python.

```
import serial

s = serial.Serial(port="COM3")
s.read(10)
```

It makes the connection but it just keeps loading and doesn't give any output.

I also Tried:

```
ser = serial.Serial()
ser.baudrate = 9600
ser.port = 'COM3'
print(ser)
```

and this is the output:

```
Serial<id=0x192eaed4c40, open=True>(port='COM3', baudrate=9600, bytesize=8, parity='N', 
stopbits=1, timeout=None, xonxoff=False, rtscts=False, dsrdtr=False)
```

Thank you.

Comment: *"It makes the connection but it just keeps loading..."* -- What is your definition of *"loading"*?  Have you studied the [interface document for the device](http://www.visiontechshop.com/media/PW-200RS%20POS,ECR%20PROTOCOL_190313.pdf)?  Have you verified the protocol selection (there's five (5) choices)?  Seems like you're trying to wing it without RTM.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't set a **timeout** that's why it never replied back. Now it does but it returns **b' '** @sawdust

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import serial


ser = serial.Serial(
    port = "COM2",
    timeout = 1,
    baudrate=9600,
    parity=serial.PARITY_EVEN,
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    bytesize=serial.SEVENBITS,




)

ser.write(str.encode("W"))


weight = ser.read(8)
print(weight.decode('ascii'), weight)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the device you are connected to, doesn't write 10 bytes, your read call will block until it has gotten all those 10 bytes.

Typically, you as a reader have to  say to the device that "hey, im here, could you give me data", and only then they will return you something. Also, you can check `ser.in_waiting` property to see if there is any data that can be read (and how much of data there is)

Comment: Thank you. How do I tell that to the device?. I tried "***ser.inWaiting() print(ser.read(0))***". And I'm getting **b' '** as an output

Comment: document @sawdust provides some pointers. It also has phone number/email where you can option a protocol description..

Answer (score 0):

You want to get the input from the weight scale device. You should follow the following steps:

1. Firstly, check the connection between the device and computer is normal (cable, USB port, computer). You can use the terminal software.
2. If the connection is ok. Now let's start with the following code:

```
port='COM8',
 baudrate = 2400,
 parity=serial.PARITY_EVEN,
 stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
 bytesize=serial.SEVENBITS,
 timeout=None
)

while 1:
 x = ser.readline()
 print(x)
```